# ng-click not working when in modal window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm using [Magnificent Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) in conjunction with Angular.

It works quite well when the modal windows are triggered by regular links, but when I try to dynamically open a modal, the ng-clicks on it don't work. I click the button and nothing happens, not even an error message.

HTML:

```
<div class="white-popup mfp-hide" id="saved-game-modal">
    <p>Would you like to continue your saved game?</p>
    <button ng-click="continueGame()">Yes</button>
    <button onclick='jQuery.magnificPopup.close()'>No</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
myController.controller('myController',['$scope', function($scope) {

   jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
       items : {
         src: '#saved-game-modal'
       },
       type: 'inline'
   }, 0);

   $scope.continueGame = function() {
      alert('here');

   };
}]);
```

How can I make the angular code work on it?

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/w544vpfu/14/

Comment: It looks like it occurs when you try to open up the modal in the scopes scope(controller). If you move the code down to document.ready (the code that opens the modal), then everything behaves as expected (which is still opening it dynamically). This isn't really an answer to why it won't work from within your controller... hopefully it helps you trouble shoot a little more though

Comment: This is probably why you aren't supposed to use JQuery with Angular. If all you want is a modal window, you could easily achieve that by adding/removing css classes, which angular wouldn't be so pissy about.

Comment: It's a timing issue. If you keep it in the controller and wrap it in a `$timeout` it will work too. Best practice is to put it in a directive though.

Comment: Thanks, @Steve. Which part of the code would go on the directive?

Comment: Controller is instantiated before the directive is fully compiled, put the jQuery.magnificPopup.open(...) in the directive and it should work I believe